# Conflito entre jquery e min-jquery

Tags: jquery

estou com problemas, pois o meu código ta dando conflito com o minjquery, não sei oq acontece, quando coloco ele todos os meus outros códigos que tenho não funcionam.... Me ajudem por favor!

http://www.redepurple.com.br/social/Code/chatjs/jquery.js

Obrigada a todos pela ajuda, resolvi colocando a última versão do Jquery, que foi a única que funcionou com todos os scripts juntos, e tirei também um outro que estava dando "conflito" de outro plugin.

Comment: Você está colocando os dois de uma vez ou é quando coloca o `.min` que dá problema ?

Comment: Porque usar ambos?

Comment: O min eu uso no meu outro projeto, e o jquery eu uso em um chat. Quando eu tiro o jquery, funciona o meu outro projeto, quando eu boto para de funcionar. E aí eu fico nessa, sem saber o que fazer

Comment: Por favor, gente queria muito que funcionasse :\

Comment: E assim, o que para de funcionar é um Jquery básico, como enviar um formulário POST, coisas simples, estranho...

Comment: Dá-te algum erro na consola quando tiras o jQuery 1.3?

Comment: Olha não sei o que é consola, mas o que acontece é que tudo para de funcionar, quando eu envio uma mensagem a página da refresh em vez de funcionar a function

Comment: @TenaAndrade vamos devagar. Coloque o `.min` do jQuery na página, salve. Depois abra sua página no navegador, aperte CTRL SHIFT J no teclado. Abrirá um Console de Informações. Atualiza a página e veja o erro que dá. Mas o Sérgio está certo provavelmente, você está colocando uma biblioteca em cima da outra.

Comment: Obrigada lindo @Gumball dá isso: VM2515:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: scrollcode is not defined

Comment: Haaaa @TenaAndrade. Pode ser que você esteja colocando o script embaixo dos outros códigos. O `.min` tem que ser o primeiro script de todos. Daí depois vem o script do `scrollcode`. É o que eu imagino, por enquanto...

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que vejo na tua página estás a carregar o jQuery 1.3, 1.7 e 2.0 em sitios diferentes, isso gera conflitos e na verdade só precisas de um deles. O que der conflito é provavelmente por teres código antigo, mudando esse código o problema deve ficar resolvido. Nunca é bom carregar versões diferentes da mesma biblioteca.

Deixa somente o jQuery mais moderno (2.0) e coloca aqui no site novas perguntas que possas ter com eventuais erros que vejas na consola ter na consola.

O que pode ser o teu problema é que páginas diferentes vão buscar o jQuery a diretorias diferentes. Nesse caso não há sobreposição de bibliotecas e, apesar de ser sempre bom usar versões mais modernas, não é urgente mudar e pode funcionar com ambas.

Pelo que encontro tens

```
<script src="assets/plugins/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script> // jQuery v1.7.2
```

e ainda esse link que indicas na pergunta com `http://www.redepurple.com.br/social/Code/chatjs/jquery.js`, que é a versão 1.3...

Se queres mais ajuda que isto tens de especificar qual a página que dá problemas e colocar aqui o HTML dessa página. O ideal é isolar o código que não funciona e mostrar aqui só isso.

Answer (score 3):

A versão .min não se trata de uma versão com recursos reduzidos, mas sim compactada, ou seja, ela é mais leve para carregar, mas tem todos os recursos da versão descompactada, em geral você usa as versões completas em ambientes de desenvolvimento, pois elas tem alguns recursos de debug e podem ser analisadas mais facilmente em caso de erros e problemas, e usa as versões .min em ambiente de produção, para ficar mais leve o carregamento e não mostrar mensagens de erro.

Você não deve carregar varias versões do jquery uma sobre a outra, escolha uma para trabalhar e carregue apenas ela. Em projetos novos eu aconselho usar a ultima versão e caso algum plugin/complemento (como o seu chat) não funcione corretamente, carregue o plugin [migrate](https://jquery.com/download/#jquery-migrate-plugin).

Answer (score 1):

Estava dando uma olhada no seu código fonte e encontrei o que provavelmente seja o problema.

Veja na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acho que essa deve ser a página que você está fazendo.
Nesse caso veja que o plugin de **jQuery** está depois do **Jquery Form**.

Ele tem que vir antes. Na verdade, o jQuery ou jQuery Min tem que vir primeiro, antes de qualquer outro plugin que use jQuery. Seria bom você colocar esses scripts antes de fechar a tag `</body>`.

Se não for essa página, nos mostre como está o código fonte (não tudo) só a parte dos scripts, que está com problemas.